# Python3.6 Crashing

Tags: python, linux

Python is crashing when trying to execute any command.
I am getting below error when trying to execute any python command on the python CLI prompt. It was working until I installed package readline for support of history commands.

---

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Jun  7 2017, 17:51:03)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print a
*** Error in `python3': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f25f905f0a0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7ada4)[0x7f25f822dda4]
python3(PyOS_Readline+0xec)[0x5c8fdc]
python3[0x446410]
python3[0x447d58]
python3(PyTokenizer_Get+0x9)[0x448b59]
python3[0x44499d]
python3(PyParser_ASTFromFileObject+0x89)[0x427589]
python3(PyRun_InteractiveOneObject+0x11b)[0x42779b]
python3(PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags+0x5e)[0x427aee]
python3(PyRun_AnyFileExFlags+0x3c)[0x427bfc]
python3(Py_Main+0xc54)[0x43a8e4]
python3(main+0x162)[0x41d722]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f25f81d4b35]
python3[0x41d7e1]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0066c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 276018                             /opt/python36/bin/python3.6
0086b000-008cf000 rw-p 0026b000 ca:01 276018                             /opt/python36/bin/python3.6
008cf000-00900000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
01151000-0121e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f25f13e8000-7f25f13fd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262171                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.3-20140911.so.1
7f25f13fd000-7f25f15fd000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 262171                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.3-20140911.so.1
7f25f15fd000-7f25f15fe000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 262171                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.3-20140911.so.1
7f25f15fe000-7f25f161b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262226                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7f25f161b000-7f25f181a000 ---p 0001d000 ca:01 262226                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7f25f181a000-7f25f181f000 rw-p 0001c000 ca:01 262226                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7f25f181f000-7f25f1844000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262222                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7f25f1844000-7f25f1a44000 ---p 00025000 ca:01 262222                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7f25f1a44000-7f25f1a45000 rw-p 00025000 ca:01 262222                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7f25f1a45000-7f25f1a80000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 280193                     /opt/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/readline.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f25f1a80000-7f25f1c80000 ---p 0003b000 ca:01 280193                     /opt/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/readline.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f25f1c80000-7f25f1c89000 rw-p 0003b000 ca:01 280193                     /opt/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/readline.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
7f25f1c89000-7f25f1c8a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f25f1c8a000-7f25f81b3000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 3494                       /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f25f81b3000-7f25f836b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262179                     /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f25f836b000-7f25f856a000 ---p 001b8000 ca:01 262179                     /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f25f856a000-7f25f856e000 r--p 001b7000 ca:01 262179                     /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f25f856e000-7f25f8570000 rw-p 001bb000 ca:01 262179                     /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f25f8570000-7f25f8575000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f25f8575000-7f25f8676000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262187                     /lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f25f8676000-7f25f8875000 ---p 00101000 ca:01 262187                     /lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f25f8875000-7f25f8876000 r--p 00100000 ca:01 262187                     /lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f25f8876000-7f25f8877000 rw-p 00101000 ca:01 262187                     /lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f25f8877000-7f25f8879000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262213                     /lib64/libutil-2.17.so
7f25f8879000-7f25f8a78000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 262213                     /lib64/libutil-2.17.so
7f25f8a78000-7f25f8a79000 r--p 00001000 ca:01 262213                     /lib64/libutil-2.17.so
7f25f8a79000-7f25f8a7a000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 262213                     /lib64/libutil-2.17.so
7f25f8a7a000-7f25f8a7c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262185                     /lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f25f8a7c000-7f25f8c7c000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 262185                     /lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f25f8c7c000-7f25f8c7d000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 262185                     /lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f25f8c7d000-7f25f8c7e000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 262185                     /lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f25f8c7e000-7f25f8c95000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262205                     /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f25f8c95000-7f25f8e94000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 262205                     /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f25f8e94000-7f25f8e95000 r--p 00016000 ca:01 262205                     /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f25f8e95000-7f25f8e96000 rw-p 00017000 ca:01 262205                     /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f25f8e96000-7f25f8e9a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f25f8e9a000-7f25f8eba000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262172                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f25f8f02000-7f25f90a7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f25f90a7000-7f25f90ae000 r--s 00000000 ca:01 3493                       /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f25f90ae000-7f25f90b2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f25f90b6000-7f25f90b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f25f90b9000-7f25f90ba000 r--p 0001f000 ca:01 262172                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f25f90ba000-7f25f90bb000 rw-p 00020000 ca:01 262172                     /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f25f90bb000-7f25f90bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fffd5ed8000-7fffd5ef9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffd5f22000-7fffd5f24000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fffd5f24000-7fffd5f26000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update (12 June 2017):** 
Though I have come out of crashing scenario on the python CLI by removing the last package(readline) which probably was causing the crash. Now, the original question still remains, why python is crashing when I install readline. I would like to have history commands for which I tried installing readline using pip. I believe I am not going off-topic.
Strace output also do not provide a indicator of the issue.

Comment: did you uninstall anything related to python? Did you try reinstalling it again from binaries?

Comment: Did you try to remove the last installed package?

Comment: If you tried to remove the last python3 package and simply replace it with 3.6, you're in for a rough time. Can confirm, currently on a fresh linux install for completely unrelated reasons...

Comment: I built it from sources. 2.7 and 3.6 resides on the system in different paths. 2.7 works like a charm. 3.6 is giving problem. @Liliane, the problem was due to 'readline' which I installed for history commands on the prompt. After removing, it works. Though I am still left without history commands on the prompt. I am already having rough time with 3.6. Nonetheless I have 2.7 to fallback for most of my requirements.

Comment: Side note: `print a` is invalid syntax in python3 - print is now used as a function - `print(a)`

Comment: @swalladge , noted, thanks. My bad,  I am switching between versions 2 and 3 frequently. However the problem is there for which ever command I execute like "import os"